# how to focus newly created object in ListView in XAF?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

On Creating the new object and after "Save and Close" action, its not showing the object created as the focused object in the list view when i change the DataAccessMode to Server.

Answer (score 0):

As with all things DevExpress, the best place to look is their [support forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). There are at least a couple of helpful answers there [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q414118) and [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q472165).

As Dennis explains:

> Subscribe to the `NewObjectViewController.ObjectCreated` event and in
>   its event handler, subscribe to the `args.ObjectSpace.Committed` event.
>   In the Committed event handler, you can set the `ListView.CurrentObject`
>   property to the object remembered on the previous step
>   (`args.CreatedObject`).